# Call function in fragment from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, methods, tabs

**Edit**
**fragment A** with **function A1**
**fragment B** with **function B1**
**Two tabs** in main activity
tabA got fragment A
tabB got fragment B
my problem is : call function A1 from main activity

```
 //here i create taps and fragment into viewpaper

 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(),"ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(),"TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}



 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String tittle){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(tittle);
}
 }
```

Comment: go through this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, you could just save an instance of the fragment directly in your Activity like this

```
private OneFragment f1;
private TwoFragment f2;

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    f1 = new OneFragment();
    f2 = new TwoFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(f1,"ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(f2,"TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

then anywhere in your activity you want to use them just call

```
f1.myMethod();
f2.myMethod();
```

You could also just save your adapter and use it to access the Fragments, as in

```
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(),"ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(),"TWO");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and to access them in the Activity call

```
OneFragment f1 = (OneFragment)adapter.getItem(0);
TwoFragment f2 = (TwoFragment)adapter.getItem(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `broadcastreceiver`

In **fragment A**

```
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "BROADCAST_ACTION";

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null &&
                intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                //Call your function A
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(
            context).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

In your **activity** where you want to call fragment method call send broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentA.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```